# How to create a json file in R with list with lists as elements with fromJson()

Tags: r, json

I am trying to create a .json file. The `third` element should be a list with lists as elements.

What am I doing wrong?

Bellow is the json file I created with R:

```
{
  "list1": [
      "element1"
    ],
    
  "list2": [
      "element2"
    ],
    
  "List_with_lists_as_elements": [
    "Child1":{
      "Name": "Child1",
      
      "Child1_Title": [
        "Title1",
        "Title2",
        "Title3"]
        
        ,
      "Child1_Subtitle": [
        "Subtitle_1",
        "Subtitle_2",
        "Subtitle_3"
      ]
    },
    "Child2":{
      "Name": "Child2",
      
      "Child2_Title": [
        "Title1",
        "Title2",
        "Title3"]
        
        ,
      "Child2_Subtitle": [
        "Subtitle2_1",
        "Subtitle2_2",
        "Subtitle2_3"
      ]
    },
    
    "Child3":{
      "Name": "Child3",
      
      "Child2_Title": [
        "Title1",
        "Title2",
        "Title3"]
        
        ,
      "Child2_Subtitle": [
        "Subtitle3_1",
        "Subtitle3_2",
        "Subtitle3_3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I then save this as `example_json.json` and upload using `fromJSON(txt = 'example_json.json')`, and I have a error message, probably because I dont know quite well create a `.json` file:

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  parse error: after array element, I expect ',' or ']'
          _as_elements": [     "Child1":{       "Name": "Child1",     
                     (right here) ------^
```

How can I create a .json file that gives me a list with lists() ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have keys in your array :

```
...
  "List_with_lists_as_elements": [
    "Child1":{
      "Name": "Child1",
...
    },
    "Child2":{
      "Name": "Child2",
...
    },
    "Child3":{
      "Name": "Child3",
...
    }
  ]
...
```

You have a `Name` field which contains the key values, so you can probably just remove the keys:

```
...
  "List_with_lists_as_elements": [
    {
      "Name": "Child1",
...
    },
    {
      "Name": "Child2",
...
    },
    {
      "Name": "Child3",
...
    }
  ]
...
```